# Element-wise multiplication of column-vector and matrix

Tags: matlab

I have an `n-by-1` column-vector `A`, and an `n-by-m` matrix `B`. I want to multiply `A` by each column of `B`, element-wise, to create a matrix `n-by-m` matrix `C`.

For example:

```
% Input
A = [1; 2; 3];
B = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12];
C = % Some function of A and B

% Output:
C = [1 2 3 4; 10 12 14 16; 27 30 33 36]
```

My question: Can this be done in one line, without having to create a loop? (MATLAB 8.1)

Comment: `C = B .* repmat(A, 1, size(B, 2))` is one (old, inefficient) way; `C = bsxfun(@times, A, B)` is newer syntax and much better.   NB:  In your example, you've constructed `C` transposed with respect to how it would actually come out (it's `m-by-n`, but you said it should be `n-by-m`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `bsxfun`. The achieve the result you want you just:

```
C = bsxfun(@times, A, B);
```

Check the full list of functions supported [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and here [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun).